# How to add to the Categories property of a (Calendar)Item in Exchange Web Services?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

The below SOAP call will update the *entire* list of categories (previous entries will be gone), but I want to add one or more.

```
<soapenv:Envelope [snip]>
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
      <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:UpdateItem ConflictResolution="AutoResolve" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToNone">
         <mes:ItemChanges>
            <typ:ItemChange>
               <typ:ItemId Id="AQMk[snip]AAAA==" ChangeKey="DwA[snip]JPV57"/>
               <typ:Updates>
                  <typ:SetItemField>
                     <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Categories"/>
                     <typ:CalendarItem>
                        <typ:Categories>
                          <typ:String>TIMETELL</typ:String>
                        </typ:Categories>
                     </typ:CalendarItem>
                  </typ:SetItemField>
               </typ:Updates>
            </typ:ItemChange>
         </mes:ItemChanges>
      </mes:UpdateItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried AppendToItemField instead of SetItemField, but Categories is not a 'appendable' property (ErrorInvalidPropertyAppend - Only To, Cc, Bcc, Required, Optional, Resources, Body, and ReplyTo are).

Is there a way to *add* Categories strings?

Glen Scales' answer in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/3f57c2ae-fb97-4fca-997e-4150c0208b9b) suggests that I would have to refresh the entire categories list but he's not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I want is indeed not possible, [the entire list of categories must be updated](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/3f57c2ae-fb97-4fca-997e-4150c0208b9b).

Also note that "[Stamping a contact item with a category doesn't modify the Master Category List](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/8de0270f-5afc-4b90-9c1a-5a0fae33a9ab), which is what Outlook uses to display the drop down. If you want your category to appear in the drop down, you must add it to the MCL."
And updating the MCL must be done differently in [Exchange 2007](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/9177b31f-c6d3-4278-845a-008292fdf586) or [later versions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/e5c5f072-0b5c-49ce-9db7-57f76f5e011e),
["because the Master category list is stored in a hidden item in the mailbox - EWS doesn't allow you to access hidden items so there's no real workarounds. You can however do this with any of the other Exchange API's such as Mapi, Exoledb or WebDAV."](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/e67602ae-fae4-4f7b-b85f-dd3ed76e6b9f)